# A remote instance with the same instance id already exists

Tags: servicenow

The above error shows up though this is the first update source i am creating for the instance.

I am trying to move updates from prod to a non prod instance. where prod is in *eureka* and non prod is in *FUJI patch 2*.

I have already looked into 
http://wiki.servicenow.com/index.php?title=Transferring_Update_Sets#
and [Transferring Update sets - Connection Fails](http://wiki.servicenow.com/index.php?title=Transferring_Update_Sets#)  But these haven't helped much.

Can someone help me understand what an instance id is exactly? (the datatype of it and the value assigned to it)
Is there any possibility that two instances to have same instance ID.

I also observe that in the list view, the instance ID for existing update sources are all blank. Could that be an issue ?

Answer (score 2):

Instance ID is a globally unique ID across all ServiceNow instances. You can see it by checking the `/stats.do` page for any instance.

Look in your `sys_update_set_source` table. There's an `instance_id` field. This error message is telling you that the target instance (connection to which you are in the process of validating at the time of this error message) has an instance ID which already exists in the local instance's `sys_update_set_source` table.

You're either adding a new update set source or making an instance your TeamDev hub/parent and it's already there.

Comment: I see that "instance id" is empty for other update sources. Though they have a different URL, does having an empty instance id be an issue?

Comment: removed the other update sources having "empty" instance id. That fixed the issue. (Got  a warning for moving updates across eureka to fuji p4)